# ListItem avatar won't render

Tags: javascript, react-native, listitem

I have a series of `ListItems` that I am generating like so:

```
        <ScrollView>
            {
                this.state.results.map((item, i) => (
                    <ListItem key={i}
                              leftAvatar={{ source: {uri: item.image} }}
                              subtitle={
                                  <Text>{ this.createInfo(item) }</Text>
                              }
                              title={ item.key }
                              onPress={() => navigate('Route', { key: item.key, location: this.state.location })}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </ScrollView>
```

The subtitle and title render fine, but for some reason, no matter what I do, I can't get the avatar prop to show up. I've tried using both the avatar and leftAvatar prop, neither work. I've also tried hardcoding the source uri for the avatar to an image, url, and that doesn't work either, so I know that it's not due to `item.image` being malformed. All I see is a slight indent to the left of my title, indicating that an avatar should be there.

Comment: Can you add the library and the version you're using and the `item.image` url

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after reading this discussion: [https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/444

Instead of using leftAvatar try:

`avatar={<Image source={require('../images/icon-settings.png')}/>}`]